# Why does convert png->jpg blow a picture up to the original size?

Tags: imagemagick

I have a png whose width is 2551 pixels and whose height is 3578 pixels.

On this png, I use the `-crop` option of `convert` to cut out an image whose dimensions are 2362 x 3389 pixels:

```
convert original_2551x3578.png -crop 2362x3389+94+94 crop_2362x3389.png
```

This works as intended.

Then, I use `convert` to create a jpg:

```
convert crop_2362x3389.png -format jpg -flatten -background white out.jpg
```

I expected this command to produce a jpg with the same dimension (2362 x 3389). Much to my surprise, the produced jpg has the dimension 2551 x 3578 pixels (which is the same as the original image).

So it seems that somehow the original size is stored along with `crop_2362x3389.png`.

How can I use `convert` to convert a png into a jpg and have it keep the dimension of `crop_2362x3389.png`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this is that when you do your initial crop, the image *"remembers"* it was part of a larger image and where in that image it used to be.

You can see this if you do your original crop and then run `identify` and look at the 4th field, just left of `8-bit`.

```
convert original_2551x3578.png -crop 2362x3389+94+94 crop_2362x3389.png
```

[image]

You can also tell ImageMagick to *"forget"* it by using `+repage` like this:

```
# Repage after changing geometry to forget earlier geometry
convert original_2551x3578.png -crop 2362x3389+94+94 +repage crop_2362x3389.png

# Check IM has forgotten image used to be a part of a bigger one
identify crop_2362x3389.png
crop_2362x3389.png PNG 2362x3389 2362x3389+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 15.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution. The geometry after the `-crop` parameter must be followed by a `!`:

```
convert original_2551x3578.png -crop 2362x3389+94+94! crop_2362x3389.png
```

This works as intended.